# clang format break before double colon

Tags: c++, namespaces, format, clang-format

I'm currently applying clang formatting incrementally over a code base and came up with a scenario where it is giving a result that is not what we really want with the line breaking location of :: take the following example.

```
// Manual format was.
bool
foo::MyLongClassName::MyLongFunctionName(
  const Type1& Argument1,
  const Type2& Argument2);

// After clang format.
bool foo::MyLongClassName::
  MyLongFunctionName(const Type1& Argument1,
                     const Type2& Argument2);
```

My co-worker had the review comment:

> I always prefer to keep the function name next to the double colon, as it makes searching for a method implementation easy.

Is there a way to get clang format to change the side the line break occurs on?

E.g. so it outputs instead like:

```
// After clang format.
bool foo::MyLongClassName
::MyLongFunctionName(const Type1& Argument1,
                     const Type2& Argument2);
```

Comment: You can find various options [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Comment: Yes, I have been using that as a reference but have not had any luck finding a way to change the layout behaviour.

Comment: what is your expected output. Can you mention that code on your question

Comment: I've updated to add an example at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For now my work around has been to apply a post clang format hack to move the double colon manually with iterating over the lines of the file and running a perl regex.

```
  # Hack - fix breaking after scoping operator, instead we want the
  # break to be before the scoping operator so we move it down a line.
  if ($line =~ /^.+::$/ &&
      $lines[$lineNo + 1] =~ /^  [A-Z].+$/)
  {
    $line = substr($line, 0, -2);
    $lines[$lineNo + 1] = "::".substr($lines[$lineNo + 1], 2);
  }
```